# Flutter Firebase/Firestore write to multiple tables at once

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase as backend to my Flutter project. I need to write to multiple tables in one transaction. Now I have:

```
await _databaseReference
      .collection('user_data')
      .document(uid)
      .setData(userData);
await _databaseReference
      .collection('company_data')
      .document(uid)
      .setData(companyData);
```

But this these are 2 transactions, so 1 could ends successfully but another one could fail and I want to prevent to happening this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a [Batched Write](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html), which "is a series of write operations to be performed as one unit", as follows:

```
var batch = _databaseReference.batch();
batch.setData(
      _databaseReference.collection('user_data').document(uid),
      userData
);
batch.setData(
      _databaseReference.collection('company_data').document(uid),
      companyData
);
await batch.commit();
```

---

Following Rahul Vyas comment below, note that a batch can contain, at the same time, some `set`, `update` and `delete` operations to be executed on different documents (potentially in different collections, as shown above). Look at the *Methods* section in the [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!! Is Firebase team planning to add Flutter to documentation to firebase site? I mean with some code snippets. Thanks

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help you! "Is Firebase team planning to add Flutter to documentation to firebase site?" -> I don't know.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec is it possible to insert and update in batch? for example, I want to call set at one location and update at another location. Is it possible?

Comment: @RahulVyas Yes it is totally possible: a batch can contain set, update and delete operations. Look at the methods: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch-class.html

Comment: @RahulVyas I've also updated the answer with this info. You may upvote the answer ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm using the real-time database. Can you update your answer with some pseudo-code? Or it would be great if you use a flutter code example.

Comment: Oh, I would then suggest you write anew question because it is radically different with the RTDB (compared to Firestore)

Comment: ok, thanks. btw I tried but there is no such method as a batch. We have run transaction method

Comment: You shoud use the [update()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/update.html) method

Comment: Look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields for the concept of updating several nodes at the same time

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec What is the best way to find paths of nodes at multiple locations and update them? Basically, lets say I want to update userName at user Object and I want all the references of User Object to be updated. How we can achieve this?